# C# mongo db driver randomly cannot connect to db

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have console app that calls mongo db by C# mongo driver in separate thread. Connection pool limit is 10, connection string is: mongodb+srv://login:pass@address/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority&connect=replicaSet

in half of times when I launch my console app it falls after 30 seconds of timeout. When I restart app it will work fine with 50% probability. If first operation falls - any other will fall too. If first is OK, any other will work fine.

Exceptions:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector,
>   LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000
>   } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode
>   : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers :
>   [], DnsMonitorException : "DnsClient.DnsResponseException: Unhandled
>   exception  ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot read byte 277,
>   out of range.    at DnsClient.DnsDatagramReader.ReadByte()    at
>   DnsClient.DnsDatagramReader.ReadLabels()    at
>   DnsClient.DnsDatagramReader.ReadQuestionQueryString()    at
>   DnsClient.DnsRecordFactory.ReadRecordInfo()    at
>   DnsClient.DnsMessageHandler.GetResponseMessage(ArraySegment`1
>   responseData)    at DnsClient.DnsUdpMessageHandler.Query(IPEndPoint
>   server, DnsRequestMessage request, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   DnsClient.LookupClient.ResolveQuery(IReadOnlyCollection`1 servers,
>   DnsMessageHandler handler, DnsRequestMessage request, Boolean
>   useCache, LookupClientAudit continueAudit)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   DnsClient.LookupClient.ResolveQuery(IReadOnlyCollection`1 servers,
>   DnsMessageHandler handler, DnsRequestMessage request, Boolean
>   useCache, LookupClientAudit continueAudit)    at
>   DnsClient.LookupClient.QueryInternal(IReadOnlyCollection`1 servers,
>   DnsQuestion question, Boolean useCache)    at
>   DnsClient.LookupClient.Query(String query, QueryType queryType,
>   QueryClass queryClass)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.DnsClientWrapper.ResolveSrvRecords(String
>   service, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.DnsMonitor.Monitor()" }.)'
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
>     MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.ServerSelectors.IServerSelector,
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.ClusterDescription)
>     MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>     MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedAsync(MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.ServerSelectors.IServerSelector,
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.ClusterDescription,
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task, System.TimeSpan,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken)
>     System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>     MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServerAsync(MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.ServerSelectors.IServerSelector,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken)
>     System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>       ...
>       [Call Stack Truncated]

Inner:

> A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using
>   CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors =
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector,
>   LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000
>   } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode
>   : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers :
>   [], DnsMonitorException : "DnsClient.DnsResponseException: Unhandled
>   exception  ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot read byte 277,
>   out of range.    at DnsClient.DnsDatagramReader.ReadByte()    at
>   DnsClient.DnsDatagramReader.ReadLabels()    at
>   DnsClient.DnsDatagramReader.ReadQuestionQueryString()    at
>   DnsClient.DnsRecordFactory.ReadRecordInfo()    at
>   DnsClient.DnsMessageHandler.GetResponseMessage(ArraySegment`1
>   responseData)    at DnsClient.DnsUdpMessageHandler.Query(IPEndPoint
>   server, DnsRequestMessage request, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   DnsClient.LookupClient.ResolveQuery(IReadOnlyCollection`1 servers,
>   DnsMessageHandler handler, DnsRequestMessage request, Boolean
>   useCache, LookupClientAudit continueAudit)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   DnsClient.LookupClient.ResolveQuery(IReadOnlyCollection`1 servers,
>   DnsMessageHandler handler, DnsRequestMessage request, Boolean
>   useCache, LookupClientAudit continueAudit)    at
>   DnsClient.LookupClient.QueryInternal(IReadOnlyCollection`1 servers,
>   DnsQuestion question, Boolean useCache)    at
>   DnsClient.LookupClient.Query(String query, QueryType queryType,
>   QueryClass queryClass)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.DnsClientWrapper.ResolveSrvRecords(String
>   service, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.DnsMonitor.Monitor()" }.

I asked our NodeJS developer and he answered that he have no such problem. Does anybody faced with this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using ip address instead of server name to see if that helps with name resolution and timeouts

Comment: Also, check the state of your replicaset, something looks off ( state disconnected)

Comment: @Jawad I use mongo atlas, so I think it's better to use provided connection string. According mongo atlas metrics it works fine

Comment: @AlexZaitsev, How did u get this issue solved? I am getting same exception 100% times since yesterday. Can't find a single clue.

Comment: @pgcan, It has still not been resolved. I noticed that issue can be reproduced when connecting from my local pc on Windows. Despite this, it works fine on my aws virtual machines

Comment: @AlexZaitsev, thanks for your response. I also have VS2019 + Windows but it has been working for last 1 week and suddenly started failing. Anyways, i will post my solution once i find the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting the exact error for last one day. I am not sure the exact problem but it is definitely related to what network I use. I tested by connecting my dev machine to my mobile's hot-spot and it worked. But when I again switched to broadband connection and it fails.

Hope it helps someone.

I have also raised a bug on mongodb support. Here is the [link](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-3015).

**EDIT:**

Finally got it fixed by upgrading the "**DnsClient**" nuget package to version 1.3.0.